# Anova continuous predictor categorical outcome variable

Tags: anova, variable

I am trying to find the effect of blood pH values(continuous variable) in three groups of patients (categorical data) with different neurological outcomes. Is it correct to use one way ANOVA test here.
pH is the predictor variable and neurological outcome is the outcome variable

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! What is the question you have to ask your data, and how do you see ANOVA addressing it?

Comment: I want to know if pH values are significantly associated with poorer neurological outcome.

Comment: I have pH values of pts who had no neurological problems, who had stroke in the initial phase of illness, stroke in the later part of their illness.

Comment: Checking if pH is the same in the three groups would be the explicit question asked by an ANOVA. Is that your question?

Comment: Please say more about when the blood pH values are measured, relative to the assignment of each patient into 1 of the 3 groups, and whether they are arterial or venous measurements. Blood pH can vary very rapidly for many reasons, so I'm a little afraid that providing a statistically correct answer might still leave you with a big problem in clinical/biological interpretation.

Comment: My doubt is if we are analyzing difference of groups where independent variables are continuous against dependent variables are categorical, is it apt to use ANOVA. I read the opposite- that Anova should be used where predictor variables are categorical and outcomes continuous. This is my doubt.

Comment: What do you see as your dependent variable? Because, right now, it seems like your DV is Ph level (which is continuous) and your IV is group, which is categorical.  Or maybe it is "condition" that you want as your DV?